# Can the Cordova "Browser" platform support external domain access somehow?

Tags: cordova, browser

It is possible for a Cordova application to access multiple external domains if configured properly according to the documentation of the cordova-plugin-whitelist documentation. But if I run the same Cordova application on the "browser" target platform it does not seem to work. Is there any way to allow the Cordova app to access external domains when running on the "browser" target platform? If so, how?

Comment: The browser platform is just for development purpose, it does not have a lot of features and the most plugins will not work correctly.

Comment: Yes but I am only using stock Cordova plugins (whitelist & geolocation) which are supported for all platforms and an ability to access multiple domains _should_ be supported by "development purpose". This is slowing me down can someone help me please?

Comment: @Joerg, I have made a list of working plugin for `browser platform`. [Available  here](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/browser-platform.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways. First, if you control the remote domain's API, add CORS support. Second, try a browser plugin, like this one (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) for Chrome.

**OP NOTE:** `cordova run browser --disable-web-security` does the trick for me.

Comment: Another option is just start Chrome with –disable-web-security flag and it will do the same thing the plugin does. I think the browser platform did that automatically in the past, but not anymore (or at least I've read someone complaining somewhere because it wasn't working)

Comment: In theory - I think you can pass that via the Cordova CLI so it gets added. I know I've used the CLI to tweak the port being used.

Comment: Thank you @jcesarmobile and @raymon-camden! The shell command `cordova run browser --disable-web-security` does the trick for me. Can one of you guys please put that command in the answer? (Early bird gets the worm.)

Comment: @RaymondCamden the worm is yours

Comment: I added the note, waiting for it to be "peer reviewed". @RaymondCamden please feel free to fix my edit!

Comment: I passed peer review for the first time and accepted the answer. Thanks again @RaymondCamden and @jcesarmobile!

Comment: Looks fine to me. You could have added it as another answer though.

Comment: @RaymondCamden  reference `browser platform`. Now [available here](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/browser-platform.md) Some links in progress as of this hour.

Comment: I don't believe the browser platform corrects the issue of being prevented from making a XHR to another domain.